# help with specific texture

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, uv, shader-nodes

I'm having issues with trying to put the texture on the right on the shape on the left, can anyone give me some pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: since you didn't tell us what you did and didn't show us...i would suggest you provide your blend file. And because we don't know what you did, i can just blindly guess: did you uv unwrap?

Comment: @Chris I did uv unwrap, basically what I did was I linked 4 circles together to make that shape and then, after making the mask texture, tried to apply it to the shape. Obviously, that didn't work, so I tried to adjust the uv unwrap and it still didn't work. If you have any idea what I'm doing wrong then any tips would be helpful (I don't know how to link the blend file), thank you.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the UV map, and the geometry in edit mode? The UV map is obviously pretty borked, but I notice there’s a portion where part of the texture near the left eye seems semi-transparently overlaid over the rest. Does this portion flicker when you orbit around the mesh?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get an orthographic view with it selected and facing at it ("orthographic right" <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> in your case) you could "project from view" in the uv unwrap menu (<kbd>U</kbd>) in *Edit Mode*.

Also it looks like there might also be two planes, co-planar, mirrored, yet z-fighting. you can check by enabling *Face Orientation* in [`Viewport Overlays`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html) settings.